# SQL: Can you search in an output of tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a query to give me all the tables with a certain column name 'place'.
hereafter i want to use the output in a new query to search for a string in all the provided tables.

the query i use for listing the tables is :

```
   SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
               ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%place%'
ORDER BY    TableName
        ,ColumnName; ; ;
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL -- that is, construct the SQL query for each query and execute it.

Comment: Do you already know the column(s) in each resulting table that you want to search?

Comment: I removed the [tag:mysql] tag because this is not about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Using sp_executesql stored procedure, you can execute a SQL statement that can be reused many times or one that has been built dynamically. You can use the output in a new query.

Example:

```
--Declare variable
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Build SQL String
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT      c.name  AS ''ColumnName'',t.name AS ''TableName'' FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE ''%place%''
ORDER BY TableName, ColumnName; ; ;' 

--Execute Transact-SQL String
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

I hope you can carry on after this. You can get more information on sp_executesql [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql).